# What should I use instead of printf in Perl?

Tags: perl, printf, string-formatting

I need to use some string replacement in Perl to ease translations, i.e. replace many

```
print "Outputting " . $n . " numbers";
```

by something like

```
printf ("Outputting %d numbers", $n);
```

However, I'd like to replace printf with something easier to parse for humans, like this:

```
printX ("Outputting {num} numbers", { num => $n });
```

or generally something more Perly.

Can you recommend something (from CPAN or not) you like and use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most Templating modules on CPAN will probably do what you want.  Here's an example using [Template Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Template-Toolkit/)...

```
use Template;
my $tt = Template->new;

$tt->process( \"Outputting [% num %] numbers\n", { num => 100 } );
```

And you can mimic your required example with something like this...

```
sub printX {
    use Template;
    my $tt = Template->new( START_TAG => '{', END_TAG => '}' );
    $tt->process( \( $_[0] . "\n" ), $_[1] );
}
```

and you've got...

```
printX 'Outputting {num} numbers' => { num => 100 };
```

Answer (score 14):

What about simply:

```
 print "Outputting $n numbers";
```

That's very Perly. If you don't need any kind of fancy formatting, string interpolation is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is suitable idea in most cases I guess, however I don't always output interpolateble variables (Dumper(\%hash) comes to mind). Have to see how that works out, but I probably need something a bit more flexible...

Comment: There's an idiom to output arbitrary expressions in interpolation: print "Hash is: @{[Dumper(\%hash)]}"; It's not pretty but it works.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill I had no idea you could do this--awesome!

Answer (score 5):

The `print` builtin is very convenient for most situations. Besides variable interpolation:

```
print "Outputting $n numbers";    # These two lines
print "Outputting ${n} numbers";  # are equivalent
```

Remember that `print` can take multiple arguments, so there is no need to concatenate them first into a single string if you need to print the result of a subroutine call:

```
print "Output data: ", Dumper($data);
```

However, for outputting numbers other than simple integers, you'll probably want the formatting convenience of printf. Outputting other data types is easy with `print`, though.

You can use `join` to conveniently output arrays:

```
print join ', ', @array;
```

And combine with `map` and `keys` to output hashes:

```
print join ', ', map {"$_ : $hash{$_}"} keys %hash;
```

Use the `qq` operator if you want to output quotes around the data:

```
print join ', ', map {qq("$_" : "$hash{$_}"}) keys %hash;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking to ease translations you should consider using one of the L10n/i18n CPAN modules that are available.  Specifically, a good overview of why your approach will end up falling short is [written up as part of the Local::Maketext docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Locale::Maketext::TPJ13).

Another great module that pairs nicely with Locale::Maketext is [Locale::Maketext::Lexicon](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Locale::Maketext::Lexicon).  This allows you to use more standard localization formats such as gettext's .po/.mo files which have GUI tools to help translators work through all the text that needs translating.  Locale::Maketext::Lexicon also comes with a helper script (xgettext.pl) that helps keep your localization files up-to-date with your templates or modules that have text that need translating.  I've had very good results with this kind of setup in the past.

Comment: I'm not talking about i18n here (apart from L::M::Lexicon being completely unsuitable, more to that later ;)), but rather preparing strings for translation. At my work we currently have to use a custom translation system where strings are extracted in a weird way.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you want to have a different way of parsing strings. I would advise you not to do this. The only one who is seeing the syntax with the %d in it is the developer and he will exactly understand what is meant. The printf syntax is powerful because of the options like padding, decimals etc.

I think you want to use more a replace method. It is perlish to do s/{num}/$n/.

Comment: "The only one who is seeing the syntax with the %d in it is the developer" -> This is not the case, those strings will be seen by translators and pretty dumb ones too :) I'd be fine with printf myself but I have to think of other people...

Answer (score 1):

In light of your comment about being for translators I suggest writing a perl script that strips all `printf()` and tabulates them in an easier more translator friendly manner.

Something like this:

```
while(<>)
{
    #regex for striping printf

    #print in tabulated form
}
```

If you print out the line number too you can easily write another program to replace the translated text.

This solution wouldn't take you any longer than re-factoring away from `printf()` and it's reusable.

---

I would definitely stick with `printf()`, it's standard across many languages.

It has almost become a standard for string output. Like `i` is for `for` loops.

Comment: The problem with printf is that you also have to get the order right.  That is, if a language reverses the order of items being substituted in, the translator is SOL with some printf's (say, C).  To make translation easier, you need to use "%1$d" so they can easily move it around.  Template Toolkit makes this trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Generally answer from Draegtun is great, but if you'd need something smaller (i.e. less memory), and not as powerful you can easily do it using this function:

```
sub printX {
    my ( $format, $vars ) = @_;

    my @sorted_keys = sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } keys %{ $vars };
    my $re = join '|', map { "\Q$_\E" } @sorted_keys;

    $format =~ s/ \{ \s* ($re) \s* \} /$vars->{$1}/xg;

    print $format;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

well, perl has [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) function...
wait, do you want something like [python's string formatting with dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)?

```
 >>> print '%(key)s' % {'key': 'value'}
 value
```

mmm, I don't know something like that exist in perl...
at least not this "easy"...
maybe [Text::Sprintf::Named](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Text-Sprintf-Named-0.0300/lib/Text/Sprintf/Named.pm) can be your friend

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, I'd like to use something instead of Perl's printf, not C's printf.